# performance issue with audioreactive visuals made with pixi and p5 sound lib

Tags: javascript, performance, webgl, pixi.js

see the example [here](http://flowen.nl/experiments/audio-reactive3/)

I guess it depends on your machine, but for me, after the first song the framerate just drops like crazy. I make sure there are not more sprites than necessary (4: 2 images and 2 displacement maps).

Is this a pixi thing, perhaps WebGL? I'm not sure how to improve it or where to look for a better performance.

Comment: If you havent, then first thing i suggest is to try to track the performance with browsers profiling, like:https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling since first assumption would be, that it most often comes from javascript and that you can debug easiest. If you dont get anywhere with profiling, try sending the profiler results  to me or giving your code to review

Comment: @Hachi Thanks for replying! I recorded a cpu profile which you can download here: flowen.nl/CPU-20160406T123821.cpuprofile.zip I'm not sure where to look next.. The code can be found here: https://github.com/lowenf/audio-reactive-fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found the issue. You are adding displacementTexture to the stage (stage.addChild(displacementTexture) again and again and you are never removing it really. So your totalSpritesOnStage do not work correctly.

How about adding something like this:

```
if (stage.children.length > 4) {
    // let's destroy the sprite now
    stage.removeChildren(4);
```

It would quickly looking seem to work with that too, though I didn't check the functionality very thoroughly.

Also this bothered me personally, as the sounds were downloaded again and again :)

```
function preload(song) {
console.log('preloading song: ' + currentSong);
console.log(song.filename);
if (allSounds[song]) {
    sound = allSounds[song];
    sound.setVolume(volume);
    sound.play();
    return;
}
allSounds[song] = sound = new p5.SoundFile('songs/' + song.filename,
    onMusicLoaded,
    h.onError
);

// The volume is reset (to 1) when a new song is loaded. so we force it 
sound.setVolume(volume);
}
```

Comment: thanks Hachi! This certainly improved it by like hmmm.. 1721% ;) Thanks for giving me the extra pointer about the sounds, makes sense to save a downloaded object into an array and then check up if it exists. Double-thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this part though: allSounds[song] = sound = new p5.Sound.... If I populate an array with all the songs, shouldn't I insert them at a certain index (which is equal to 'currentSong' (which is a nr between 1-songs.length) and then check if the index already exists? Than I probably also need to make the allSounds.length = songs.length. Does this make sense?

Comment: @flowen I'm not totally sure, what you are trying to change by making the allSounds an array instead of an object. Now the purpose is just to provide a cache, so that the p5 doesn't always download and initialize the files again and again. If they are already once downloaded and initialized, I don't see a point why it should do that work again by calling p5.SoundFile. You can use any means you want for that of course.

Oh and I didn't remember to mention, that it was quite cool demo. I've heard about audio reactive stuff, but haven't really seen it in use :).

Comment: There are multiple songs, so I thought your way only cached 1 song because you overwrite it again and again, right? And thx man! I wrote a little bit about it here: https://medium.com/@flowen/diving-into-audio-reactive-visuals-on-the-web-e5c44925c1fc#.k881mwbxy there's some links in there that can show you different audio-reactive stuff with three.js. Felix Turner is my god.